# $ABCD$ is a rectangle of area $210$ cm$^2$. $L$ is a mid-point of $CD$ . $P,Q$ trisect $AB$ . $AC$ cuts $LP,LQ$ at $M,N$ respectively.

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, congruences-geometry

> $ABCD$ is a rectangle of area $210$ cm$^2$. $L$ is a mid-point of $CD$ . $P,Q$ trisect $AB$ . $AC$ cuts $LP,LQ$ at $M,N$ respectively. Find $[\Delta LMN]$

**What I Tried**: For a geometry Problem, it's always better to start with a figure :-
[image]

I have no good idea for this, it's also hard to do angle-chasing in a rectangle. And neither I find similar triangles in this picture.

It will be good if someone posts a hint to start with this.

Comment: You can work on $7\times3$ rectangle and scale by $10$ later. Easy to trisect $3$.

Comment: There are in fact some similar triangles. One pair is $BEH$ and $CFH$. There is another pair.

Comment: What is the connection of your figure with the problem? I have a mess with the names of the points.

Comment: Yes, $BEH$ and $CFH$ are similar, but hoe is going to help? After all, I am concerned about $\Delta HIE$ only .

Comment: Can anyone give me an idea to solve this?

Comment: You can use Menelaus theorem or again coordinate geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking cosmo5's advice by using a $7\times3$ rectangle then just scaling by 10:

I made my own drawing including the lines and marking the points A, B, C, D, P, Q, and L on the Desmos graphing calculator. (The rest will be algebra and geometry, so I didn't just use the graph to cheat.)

The first thing to notice is that, if A is at the origin of a graph, and B is at the point $(0, 3)$, then we know that P rests at $(0, 2)$ and Q at $(0, 1)$, thus trisecting $\overline{AB}$. This means that $\overline{CD}$ is bisected by point L at $(0, 1.5)$. Thus we know that the following lines are true: $\overline{PL}=\frac{-x}{14}+2$; $\overline{QL}=\frac{x}{14}+1$; and $\overline{AC}=\frac{3x}{7}$.

Setting the formulæ for $\overline{QL}$ and $\overline{PL}$ equal to the formula $\overline{AC}$, we can find where they intersect (thus N and M, respectively). Doing so reveals that M sits at $(4,\frac{12}{7})$ and N sits at $(\frac{14}{5},\frac{42}{35})$.

From here, we have our triangle LMN (the one in question). To figure out its area, we utilise Heron's formula which is $A=\sqrt{(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ such that $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ such that $a, b$, and $c$ are the lengths of the sides of the triangle. So, to find the lengths, we use the distance formula ($d=\sqrt{(x_{2}-x_{1})^2+(y_{2}-y_{1})^2}$) between the points. We'll define $a\equiv\overline{LM}$, $b\equiv\overline{MN}$, and $c\equiv\overline{LN}$. Doing this reveals that reveals that: $a=\sqrt{9+(1.5-\frac{12}{7})^2}$, $b=\sqrt{(4-\frac{14}{5})^2+(\frac{12}{7}-\frac{42}{35})^2}$, and $c=\sqrt{(7-\frac{14}{5})^2+(1.5-\frac{42}{35})^2}$. Plugging these into the formula gives an answer of $0.9$. Because we scaled down by 10, we know that the area of $\triangle LMN=9$.

Comment: Good work! Alternately, $[LMN] = 0.5\times MN \times h$ where $h$ is distance of $(7,0)$ from $AC$.

Comment: That was my original idea. I found this problem around noon yesterday but had to go to work shortly thereafter. I ended up doing most of the work on napkins during my break only to come home and type it up and use a calculator. My oringal solution looked a lot like $A=\sqrt{s(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)(s-\gamma)}$ such that $s=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{2}}$. Basically, it was all variables to find the relationship between everything. Since I didn't have hard numbers, I opted for Heron's formula because it relates the sides instead of me a perpendicular line to one of those or an angle.